# Evolution mail client, calendar not syncing

Tags: evolution

Using Ubuntu 17.04 and Evolution 3.22.6. Mails from Outlook.com are syncing. But Calendars and tasks do not. Any help is appreciated.

How does one add setting for the "On this computer" under "Preferences"? The edit button is always grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

To use Outlook.com in **Evolution,** you need to go to the account settings (`Edit->Preferences->Mail Accounts`).

[[image: Account settings[1]]
Add a new account, enter you adress and go to the `Receiving E-mail` section:
[image: Receiving E-mail setting]
and enter

**Host URL:** `https://outlook.live.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`

**OAB URL:** `https://outlook.live.com/OAB`

After entering your  credentials everthing should be fine (tested with Evolution 3.20.5).